# Como fazer um laço "for each" na coluna P até à última linha preenchida em VBA?

Tags: vba, excel-vba

Se definir a coluna inteira `P:P` a folha vai congelar. Como é que defino o `rng`, alguma ideia?

CÓDIGO:

```
Sub teste()
Dim rng As Range
Set rng = Range("P2:P300") 'Estou a definir até à linha 300 para não quebrar

For Each Row In rng.Rows

If Row.Value > "0" And Row.Value <= "100" Then

Range("U2").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-5]*1.69*(1+40%)"
Lastrow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Range("U2").AutoFill Destination:=Range("U2:U" & Lastrow)
Selection.NumberFormat = "0"

ElseIf Row.Value > "100" And Row.Value <= "150" Then

Range("U2").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-5]*1.69*(1+35%)"
Lastrow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Range("U2").AutoFill Destination:=Range("U2:U" & Lastrow)
Selection.NumberFormat = "0"


End If
Next Row
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Sub teste()

    rng = Columns(16).End(xlDown).Row

    MsgBox rng

    For i = 1 To rng

        If Cells(i, 16).Value > "0" And Cells(i, 16).Value <= "100" Then

            Range("U2").Select
            ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-5]*1.69*(1+40%)"
            lastrow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
            Range("U2").AutoFill Destination:=Range("U2:U" & lastrow)
            Selection.NumberFormat = "0"

        ElseIf Cells(i, 16).Value > "100" And Cells(i, 16).Value <= "150" Then

            Range("U2").Select
            ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-5]*1.69*(1+35%)"
            lastrow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
            Range("U2").AutoFill Destination:=Range("U2:U" & lastrow)
            Selection.NumberFormat = "0"

        End If

    Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Sim, até à última linha @Leandro Felipe Moreira!

Comment: Como é que defino isso em `Set rng = Range("P2:P300")`?

Comment: Então, aparentemente seu código tem alguns erros, qual é o objetivo do código? Você quer que a célula da respectiva linha receba a formula?

Comment: O código preenche até à última linha. Mas o que eu estou a perguntar é como defino para ele procurar a última linha preenchida. Não posso definir até `Range("P2:P300")`, até porque pode ser menos ou mais linhas.

Comment: Definir a `rng` fica `Set rng = Columns(16).End(xlDown).Row` e o `For` fica `For Each Row In rng`

Comment: Isso dá barraca!

Comment: Eu testei seu código e aparentemente ele respondeu corretamente

Comment: É uma expressão! Quero dizer que o código quebra em `Set rng = Columns(16).End(xlDown).Row`, não será pela definição em `Dim rng As Range`? Estás a selecionar uma coluna, certo?

Comment: Troquei seu range, vê agora. Pode tirar o `Msgbox` que eu coloquei

Comment: Excelente @ Leandro Felipe Moreira!

Comment: Está a fazer o cálculo com 35% em todas as células com diferentes valores! O Primeiro valor da célula P2 é de 170,00.